# How to fix " partial link class name finding" in selenium

Tags: selenium

I am trying to fetch data for two class name with `_2NQ7bVEP` & `_2NQ7bVEP entered`

However I am unable to use single class name to fetch both the class details.

I have tried xpath , contains method ,but nothing worked

```
WebElement ImgSection = driver.findElement(By.className("_2NQ7bVEP"));
```

I expect the output of both the class name using only class_name "_2NQ7bVEP" After this class_name anything comes it should work . link using *

Comment: What was the result and what were you expecting. Add details because it's unclear what you are asking right now.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the contains like this?

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//*[contains(@class,'_2NQ7bVEP')]");
```

or you can have a list of elements:

```
List<WebElement> listOfElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'_2NQ7bVEP')]"));
```